# MIPS assembly variable registers

Tags: optimization, assembly, mips

I have a section of code that I'd like to reuse, while changing only one register in one instruction. The initial register is `$f18` in `coproc1`, and each time this code is run I want it to use the next `COP1` register (max of 4 times). In this case I am very limited on memory and available GPR registers so I would not like to make a separate subroutine for this.

I know I can use self-modifying code to change the actual instruction, but doing so seems to require me to know the exact address of the line in question. This makes developing my code difficult because the size will constantly fluctuate until I'm finished.

Is it possible to reference a memory address by label+offset?
And is there a better way to do this using very few instructions and additional registers?

```
calc_and_add_color:
srl       $t2,  $t2, $t0
andi      $s2,  $t2, 0x1F 
mtc1      $s2,  $f22        #f22 is now red/green/blue component
cvt.s.w   $f22, $f22
mul.s     $f25, $f22, $f18  #<<<F18 HERE IS WHAT I WANT TO CHANGE
round.w.s $f25, $f25
lh        $s2,  0x0($s1)
mfc1      $s5,  $f25
addu      $s5,  $s5, $s2    #add new red comp. to existing one 
andi      $s5,  $s5, 0x1F   #cap at 31
sh        $s2,  0x0($s1)    #store it
addiu     $s1,  $s1, 0x6C0  #next color
addiu     $s2,  $r0, 0x5    #bit shifter
andi      $s5,  $fp, 0x0003 #isolate counter
bnel      $s5,  $zero, calc_and_add_color #when fp reaches zero every color has been done
addiu     $fp,  $fp, -0x1
```

Comment: You know, you could just put a label on the very instruction you wanted to modify ;)

Comment: AFAIK, MIPS has no PC-relative addressing, so this is going to be ugly. Also, self-modifying code is a nightmare on systems with caches. If you have some form of protection against modification of executable memory, you'll have to disable that too. Really, unless you're up against the last kilobyte of memory in the system, it's going to be too slow and painful to be worth it.

Comment: @Jester: Wow I feel stupid, somehow didn't think of that. Although since a label isn't an actual part of the code, I don't see why label offsets aren't allowed.

Comment: @EOF I do have less than a kilobyte of code space, but there's no protection on changing the code.

Comment: that leaves the problem of i-cache, if your machine has caches. Your loop is small, so the instructions will not be reloaded from a unified cache on their own, you'll have to add an explicit instruction to mark the current page in i-cache as invalid... Ugly.

Comment: You will need to use a `SYNCI` instruction to evict the old code from the I-cache after you modify the instruction in memory